# sql update using a list of values on a list of targets

Tags: sql, set, sql-update

I want to update a list of items using a list of values for example:

```
$fruits = "apple,banana,orange";
$prices = "10,15,20";
$sql = "UPDATE stuff SET fruit =?? ($fruits) where price in ($prices)
```

I know the "update x set a=b where c in (d)" part works, but I dont know it I can use a list of items as value for b

Comment: So you want to set fruit to multiple values in a single `UPDATE` statement?  That doesn't make sense.  `UPDATE` performs a modification of each matched row, and `fruit` can only have one value for a given row.  Maybe you want to use `INSERT` to create new rows, or maybe your statement structure doesn't match the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to split data from fruits and prices, and then join by position in the list. Its possible to do in SQL server, I don't know about your RDBMS

Comment: Or do you mean using a list of items for `d`, rather than `b`? That would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE x
SET a = CASE c
           WHEN 'c1' THEN 'b1'
           WHEN 'c2' THEN 'b2'
           ...
        END
WHERE c in ('c1', 'c2', ...)
```

Comment: no but I dont want to check anything I just want all fruits to have a price.. actually in this example its the other way around :D I just want all prices to have a fruit :D

Comment: ok nvm Ill just do it the hard way..
foreach x as y {
update bla bla
}